# How to use Python Strings when calling Windows API

Tags: python, windows

I'm trying to create a new Windows window by calling the `win32gui.CreateWindow` Function. The Window is created as expected, however the title is made up of Chinese (or other similar) characters, instead of reading "Hello, World!". [image]

By counting the number of characters and reading documentation, I guessed that windows is using double width characters and python is not. Here are some of the things I tried to make it display properly, none of these attempts worked however:

```py
def to_16(s):
    s = s.encode('utf-16')
    return "".join([format(i, "X").rjust(2,"0") for i in s])

def to_16(s):
    return ''.join([f'{c}{chr(32)}' for c in s])

def to_16(s):
    return ''.join([chr(i) for i in s.encode('utf-16')])
```

This is the code I use to create the window:

```py
import ctypes
import cython
import win32, win32gui, win32ui, win32con, win32api

LRESULT = ctypes.c_longlong

WNDPROC = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(LRESULT,
                 ctypes.wintypes.HWND,
                 ctypes.c_uint,
                 ctypes.wintypes.WPARAM,
                 ctypes.wintypes.LPARAM)

@WNDPROC
def WindowProc(hWnd:ctypes.wintypes.HWND,
               uMsg:ctypes.c_uint,
               wParam:ctypes.wintypes.WPARAM,
               lParam:ctypes.wintypes.LPARAM)->LRESULT:

    if uMsg == win32con.WM_PAINT:
        hDC, paintStruct = win32gui.BeginPaint(hWnd)
        rect = win32gui.GetClientRect(hWnd)
        win32gui.DrawText(hDC,
                          'Hello send by Python via Win32!',
                          -1,
                          rect,
                          win32con.DT_SINGLELINE | win32con.DT_CENTER | win32con.DT_VCENTER)

        win32gui.EndPaint(hWnd, paintStruct)
        return 0
    elif uMsg == win32con.WM_DESTROY:
        print('Window: destroyed')
        win32gui.PostQuitMessage(0)
        return 0
    else:
        return win32gui.DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam)

HCURSOR = ctypes.wintypes.HICON

class WNDCLASSEX(ctypes.Structure): # tagWNDCLASSEXA
    _fields_ = [("cbSize"       , ctypes.c_uint),
                ("style"        , ctypes.c_uint),
                ("lpfnWndProc"  , WNDPROC),
                ("cbClsExtra"   , ctypes.c_int),
                ("cbWndExtra"   , ctypes.c_int),
                ("hInstance"    , ctypes.wintypes.HINSTANCE),
                ("hIcon"        , ctypes.wintypes.HICON),
                ("hCursor"      , HCURSOR),
                ("hbrBackground", ctypes.wintypes.HBRUSH),
                ("lpszMenuName" , ctypes.wintypes.LPCWSTR),
                ("lpszClassName", ctypes.wintypes.LPCWSTR),
                ("hIconSm"      , ctypes.wintypes.HICON),]

def WinMain():
    print('Start...')
    hInstance = win32api.GetModuleHandle()
    hPrevInstance = None
    lpCmdLine = ''
    nCmdShow  = win32con.SW_SHOWNORMAL

    szWindowClass = 'DesktopApp'    # The main window class name.
    szTitle       = 'Hello, World!' # The string that appears in the application's title bar.

    wcex = WNDCLASSEX()
    wcex.cbSize         = ctypes.sizeof(WNDCLASSEX)
    wcex.style          = win32con.CS_HREDRAW | win32con.CS_VREDRAW
    wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WindowProc
    wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0
    wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0
    wcex.hInstance      = hInstance
    wcex.hIcon          = win32gui.LoadIcon(0, win32con.IDI_APPLICATION)
    wcex.hCursor        = win32api.LoadCursor(None, win32con.IDC_ARROW)
    wcex.hbrBackground  = ctypes.wintypes.HBRUSH(win32con.COLOR_WINDOW+1)
    wcex.lpszMenuName   = None
    wcex.lpszClassName  = szWindowClass
    wcex.hIconSm        = win32gui.LoadIcon(0, win32con.IDI_APPLICATION)
    print('Setup: done')

    wndClassAtom = 0
    try:
        wndClassAtom = ctypes.windll.user32.RegisterClassExA(wcex)
        print(f'wndClassAtom: {wndClassAtom}')
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        if wndClassAtom == 0:
            print('Call to RegisterClassEx failed!')
            return 1

    print('Class: registered')
    hInst = hInstance

    hWnd = 0
    try:
        hWnd = win32gui.CreateWindow(wndClassAtom,
                                     to_16(szTitle),
                                     win32con.WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                                     win32con.CW_USEDEFAULT, win32con.CW_USEDEFAULT,
                                     500, 100,
                                     0,
                                     0,
                                     hInstance,
                                     None)
        print(f'hWnd: {hWnd}')
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        if not hWnd:
            win32gui.UnregisterClass(wndClassAtom, hInstance)
            print('Call to CreateWindow failed!')
            return 1

    print('Window: created')

    win32gui.ShowWindow(hWnd,
                        nCmdShow)
    win32gui.UpdateWindow(hWnd)

    # Dispatch messages
    win32gui.PumpMessages()
    win32gui.UnregisterClass(wndClassAtom, hInstance)
    return 0

errCode = WinMain()
if errCode == 1: print('----------WINDOWS ERROR----------')
```

I'd love for a robust way to pass python strings to the Windows API.

Comment: Call [`RegisterClassExW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerclassexw) to register a Unicode window.

Comment: That said, I don't know why you're involving ctypes instead of using just PyWin32 (e.g. `win32gui.RegisterClass` and `win32gui.WNDCLASS`).

Comment: Thank you, this solved it for me! I'm using ctypes because WNDCLASS ["has been superseded by the WNDCLASSEX structure"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/ns-winuser-tagwndclassa). However I didn't know how to load that one with PyWin32, so I made my own.

Comment: `WNDCLASSEX` only adds `hIconSm`, if we happen to need a custom small icon. Using `win32gui.RegisterClass` and `win32gui.WNDCLASS` will work fine and be much simpler for you. The system implicitly sets `hIconSm` to `NULL` in this case. This instructs it to search the `hIcon` resource for an appropriately small icon.